# How do i get device data?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

can i get any other device related data other than those specified in UIdevice that are in settings of iphone like bluetooth, cellular data on off status ,Total memory,left memory ,batery status...etc

> I was able to get the following using UIDevice class : Name Model
>   Localized System, Version, Language  ,Country ,Application version,
>   systemName, UUID

like is there any API that helps me to retrieve device data?

What does country in UIdevice signify? used lang version or country in which i live a bit Confused.

Comment: check this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-accessing-device-data-with-uidevice-and-nslocale--mobile-11511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [ALSystemUtilities](https://github.com/andrealufino/ALSystemUtilities) library made by [Andrea Lufino](https://github.com/andrealufino), which provides information about device's battery, disk, hardware, jailbreak, localization, memory (RAM), network, processor, carrier, accessories.

Comment: sorry for asking this question but can i use this files in my proj without any problem right for Apples approval?

Comment: Sure you can. There is an app "ALSystem" that is downloadable on the App Store and uses this library.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this open-source iOS library to have an idea of what kind of device information you can get: https://github.com/leverdeterre/iAppInfos.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but if you want to try a Swift solution you can now use [Luminous](https://github.com/andrealufino/Luminous). It's written in Swift 3 and provide a lot of information about the device.